# flask app on heroku session ends after about an hour even when session is set to permanent

Tags: python, flask, session, cookies, flask-session

I have a flask application deployed on heroku and the session on it ends after about an hour.
I set session to be permanent like so:

```
@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
   session.permanent = True
```

The problem does not seem to reproduce when running the app in my pc.

Also I have other cookie setting that may be the problem, although I did not find them causing it:

```
app.config.update(
    REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE = True,
    SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=True,
    REMEMBER_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True,
    SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE='Lax',
)

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
   response.headers['Strict-Transport-Security'] = 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
   response.headers['X-Content-Type-Options'] = 'nosniff'
   response.headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'SAMEORIGIN'
   response.headers['X-XSS-Protection'] = '1; mode=block'
   response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
   response.headers["Expires"] = 0
   response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
   return response
```

Comment: can you open dev tools and show us the error?